# DEBUG: CRAWLED (200) (referer: None)

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl a webpage using **Scrapy** and **XPath**. Here are my code and logs, can someone help me. Thanks in advance!

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from crawler.items import CrawlerItem

class CrawlerSpider(Spider):
    name = "crawler"
    allowed_domains = ["dayhoctienganh.net"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://dayhoctienganh.net/trac-nghiem-tieng-anh-trinh-do-b",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        questions = Selector(response).xpath('//ol[@class="questions"]/li')
        for question in questions:
            item = CrawlerItem()
            item['quest']= question.xpath('/h3/text()').extract_first()
            item['sela']= question.xpath('/ul[@class="answers"]/li[1]/label/text()').extract_first()
            item['selb']= question.xpath('/ul[@class="answers"]/li[2]/label/text()').extract_first()
            item['selc']= question.xpath('/ul[@class="answers"]/li[3]/label/text()').extract_first()
            item['seld']= question.xpath('/ul[@class="answers"]/li[4]/label/text()').extract_first()
            item['key']= question.xpath('/ul[@class="responses"]/li[2]/text()').extract_first()
            yield item
```

```
2019-11-16 23:53:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-11-16 23:53:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-11-16 23:53:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-11-16 23:53:53 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-11-16 23:53:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://dayhoctienganh.net/trac-nghiem-tieng-anh-trinh-do-b> (referer: None)
2019-11-16 23:53:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: Have you tried `scrapy shell`? Does `//ol[@class="questions"]/li` return anything there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the source of the `start_urls` using ctrl/cmd + U, you will be unable to find `questions` class and `questions` list will be empty, which results in skipping the for loop in parse method and thus you are not getting your desired results. Moreover `answers` is also not available in the source of the webpage as well. Thus all fields of `item` will empty as well.

Comment: added a picture in my comment

Comment: In scrappy you have access to First `GET` request. The source in the picture is of all the ajax requests etc. Open source code using ctrl/cmd + U. That source is what scrappy has access to.

Comment: oh thanks a lot, does this depend on the website? because the tutorial that I followed kinda work and it was similar to my code above (using f12 and inspect)

Answer (score 0):

[Tried scrapy shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmTjq.png)

Does this mean that it returned nothing? (I'm also new to scrapy shell)

Ran

```
scrapy shell "https://dayhoctienganh.net/trac-nghiem-tieng-anh-trinh-do-b"
```

[html that i followed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYTQD.png)